# Audit trail in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, audit-trail

Following is the problem statement:

I have a database table with entries that look like (this is fictional table :-) ):

```
Company    Customer ID         Date          

Amazon            1         2012-08-30      
Amazon            2         2012-09-30
Amazon            2         2012-09-1
amazon            2         2012-12-10
eBay              1         2012-03-10
eBay              10        2012-01-01
BananaR           1         2012-02-20  
BananaR           1         2012-02-28
BananaR           1         2012-05-10
BananaR           1         2012-05-25
```

Now each entry in this table denotes the security check done for online transaction. So the 1st row would mean that "For Customer ID 1, Amazon did a online security check on 2012-08-30 for a transaction".

So, I need to figure how many additional security checks where done for the same Customer and company combination in every month **after the 1st security check**. i.e.

For customer 2, Amazon did its 1st check on 2012-09-01, then the additional ones would be ones on 2012-09-30 and 2012-12-10. So expected answer is:

```
Company      CustomerID     Month            Additional checks
Amazon          1            2012-08               0
Amazon          2            2012-09               1
Amazon          2            2012-12               1
eBay            1            2012-03               0
eBay            10           2012-01               0
BananaR         1            2012-02               1
BananaR         1            2012-05               2
```

My existing query outputs for additional checks since 1st check done in every month, but I do not know if I can back track to previous months. So my query looks like:

```
select company as 'Company',
       customer_id as 'Customer',
       format_date as 'Month',
       (add_count-1) as 'Additioanl Checks'
  from (select count(*) as add_count,
               company,
               customer_id,
               to_char(date, 'yyyy-mm') as format_date
          from my_table
          group by company, customer_id, format_date)
```

The result is get now is:

```
Company      Customer         Month       Additional Checks
Amazon         1               2012-08         0
Amazon         2               2012-09         1
**Amazon       2               2012-12         0**
eBay           1               2012-03         0
eBay           10              2012-01         0
BananaR        1               2012-02         1
**BananaR      1               2012-05         1**
```

The rows in ** are incorrect since they are counting for additional checks per month basis and not since the 1st check was done in previous months.

Comment: ‘backtracking’ should be used to mean something else (SQL is related to Logic Programming and LP does backtracking but it has nothing to do with auditing), so I edited the title of the question and added a tag as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understood your logic, you want to subtract 1 from the count for the first month, but not for subsequent months.  Here is one way:

```
select Company,
       Customer,
       to_char(date, 'yyyy-mm') as month,
       count(*) - (case
                     when to_char(min(MinDate), 'yyyy-mm') = to_char(date, 'yyyy-mm')
                     then 1
                     else 0
                   end)
  from (select t.*,
               min(date) over (partition by company, customer) as MinDate
          from t) t
  group by Company, Customer, to_char(date, 'yyyy-mm')
```

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov . . . I left the group by out of the query.  Now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
10:27:57 HR@vm_xe> l                                                              
  1  select company                                                               
  2         ,customer_id                                                          
  3         ,mon                                                                  
  4         ,sum(sign(rn-1)) cnt                                                  
  5  from (                                                                       
  6    select company                                                             
  7           ,customer_id                                                        
  8           ,to_char(dt, 'yyyy-mm') mon                                         
  9           ,row_number() over(partition by company, customer_id order by dt) rn
 10      from security_checks                                                     
 11  )                                                                            
 12  group by company, customer_id, mon                                           
 13* order by company, customer_id                                                
10:27:57 HR@vm_xe> /                                                              

COMPANY         CUSTOMER_ID MON            CNT                                    
--------------- ----------- ------- ----------                                    
Amazon                    1 2012-08          0                                    
Amazon                    2 2012-09          1                                    
Amazon                    2 2012-12          1                                    
BananaR                   1 2012-02          1                                    
BananaR                   1 2012-05          2                                    
eBay                      1 2012-03          0                                    
eBay                     10 2012-01          0                                    

7 rows selected.                                                                  

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```